# Can I use & > in a groovy script executing shell commands?

Tags: shell, groovy, scripting

Can I use & > in a groovy script executing shell commands? i.e.

```
/someDir/myScripts/stop.sh $NAME & > /someDir/something/${NAME}/logs/stop.log
```

will just

```
'/someDir/myScripts/stop.sh $NAME & > /someDir/something/${NAME}/logs/stop.log'.execute()
```

work or do i need to do something complicated?

```
cmd = "/someDir/myScripts/stop.sh $NAME & > /someDir/something/${NAME}/logs/stop.log"
['sh', '-c', cmd].execute();
```

may work better than the .execute() but i was just wondering if this is possible

if i cannot implement this i believe i can call another .sh with the command in that script but I was wondering if i could do it in the .groovy file

---

EDIT

the NAME is defined in my groovy program
(also would like to know if i need the path)
the program is just trying to stop something using a given stop.sh script
(also stop the log of that program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to invoke the shell to background a task like that.  A pure groovy solution would be to run the process with `consumeProcessOutputStream`:

```
new File("/someDir/something/${NAME}/logs/stop.log").newOutputStream { log ->
    "/someDir/myScripts/stop.sh $NAME".execute().consumeProcessOutputStream(log)
}
```